# regexp find match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm working on a regexp to find and replace all matches that don't start with **url(http**

relative paths are going to be converted to full absolut paths
ie:
url(foo/bar) > url('http://foo/bar')

match:

- url(foo/bar)
- url('foo/bar')

don't match:

- url(http://foo/bar)
- url('http://foo/bar')

This is what I've come up with so far, but I'm not 100% there

```
       $fileContents = preg_replace(
            '/url\(("|\')?(?<!(http))(.+?)("|\')?\)/i',
            'url(\'' . $glmBaseUrl . $subDir . '/$3\')',
            $fileContents
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should suffice:

```
preg_replace('/url\(\'?(?!http)([^\']+?)\'?\)/',
    "url('$glmBaseUrl$subDir\$1')", $fileContents);
```

The problem with yours is that you used negative lookbehind instead of negative lookahead. You should also use `[^\']` instead of `.`, otherwise `url('http://foo/bar')` will match by not matching the optional `'`, failing the negative lookahead because it's `'http` and not `http` and then matching the single quote with `.+?`.